# RADIUS: Accounting is not establishing the session

Tags: radius, huawei

I'm using Huawei Ne20 and a FreeRadius, the last has already been used to authentication Mikrotik accounts.

I'm getting authentication accept message, but the accounting session is not being initialized.

This is the Huawei debug. **The Authentication is initialized, but seems the huawei does not answer the accounting, the radius sent the packet with Acct-Status-Type [START] and the next packets, the flag chance to [STOP]**

```
Nov 23 18:55:36 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:56:55.778 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  Radius Sent a Packet
  Server Template: 1
  Server IP   : 172.16.72.6
  NAS IP      : 172.16.72.90
  Vpn-Instance: -
  Server Port : 1812
  NAS Port    : 1812
  Protocol: Standard
  Code    : Authentication request
  Len     : 286
  ID      : 156
  [User-Name(1)                       ] [9 ] [usertest]
  [User-Password(2)                   ] [18] [******]
  [NAS-Port(5)                        ] [6 ] [3153920]
  [NAS-IP-Address(4)                  ] [6 ] [172.16.72.90]
  [Service-Type(6)                    ] [6 ] [2] [Framed]
  [Framed-Protocol(7)                 ] [6 ] [1] [PPP]
  [Calling-Station-Id(31)             ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [NAS-Identifier(32)                 ] [9 ] [CERBERO]
  [NAS-Port-Type(61)                  ] [6 ] [15] [Ethernet]
  [NAS-Port-Id(87)                    ] [35] [slot=0;subslot=3;port=2;vlanid=0;]
Nov 23 18:55:36 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:56:55.778 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [Acct-Session-Id(44)                ] [35] [CERBERO0030200000000095bc60002040]
  [Connect-Info(77)                   ] [12] [1000000000]
  [HW-NAS-Startup-Time-Stamp(Huawei-59)] [6 ] [1542664036]
  [HW-IP-Host-Address(Huawei-60)      ] [35] [255.255.255.255 18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [HW-Connect-ID(Huawei-26)           ] [6 ] [8256]
  [HW-Version(Huawei-254)             ] [14] [Huawei NE20E]
  [HW-Product-ID(Huawei-255)          ] [7 ] [NE20E]
  [HW-Domain-Name(Huawei-138)         ] [6 ] [domain-test]
  [HW-User-Mac(Huawei-153)            ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
Nov 23 18:55:37 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:56:55.829 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  Radius Received a Packet
  Server Template: 1
  Server IP   : 172.16.72.6
  NAS IP      : 172.16.72.90
  Vpn-Instance: -
  Server Port : 1812
  NAS Port    : 1812
  Protocol: Standard
  Code    : Authentication accept
  Len     : 50
  ID      : 156
  [Framed-Protocol(7)                 ] [6 ] [1] [PPP]
  [Unknown-attr(13)                   ] [6 ] [00000001]
  [Acct-Interim-Interval(85)          ] [6 ] [900]
  [Unknown-attr(9-37)                 ] [6 ] [474f4c44]
Nov 23 18:55:37 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:56:55.873 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  Radius Sent a Packet
  Server Template: 1
  Server IP   : 172.16.72.6
  NAS IP      : 172.16.72.90
  Vpn-Instance: -
  Server Port : 1813
  NAS Port    : 1813
  Protocol: Standard
  Code    : Account request
  Len     : 312
  ID      : 18
  [User-Name(1)                       ] [9 ] [usertest]
  [NAS-Port(5)                        ] [6 ] [3153920]
  [NAS-IP-Address(4)                  ] [6 ] [172.16.72.90]
  [Framed-IP-Address(8)               ] [6 ] [10.0.0.2]
  [NAS-Identifier(32)                 ] [9 ] [CERBERO]
  [Acct-Status-Type(40)               ] [6 ] [1] [Start]
  [Acct-Delay-Time(41)                ] [6 ] [0]
  [Acct-Session-Id(44)                ] [35] [CERBERO0030200000000095bc60002040]
  [Acct-Authentic(45)                 ] [6 ] [1] [RADIUS]
  [Event-Timestamp(55)                ] [6 ] [1543035415] [2018-11-24 04:56:55]
Nov 23 18:55:37 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:56:55.873 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [NAS-Port-Type(61)                  ] [6 ] [15] [Ethernet]
  [Calling-Station-Id(31)             ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [NAS-Port-Id(87)                    ] [35] [slot=0;subslot=3;port=2;vlanid=0;]
  [Service-Type(6)                    ] [6 ] [2] [Framed]
  [Framed-Protocol(7)                 ] [6 ] [1] [PPP]
  [Connect-Info(77)                   ] [12] [1000000000]
  [Idle-Timeout(28)                   ] [6 ] [0]
  [Session-Timeout(27)                ] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-IP-Host-Address(Huawei-60)      ] [34] [10.0.0.2 18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [HW-Priority(Huawei-22)             ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-Connect-ID(Huawei-26)           ] [6 ] [8256]
  [HW-Domain-Name(Huawei-138)         ] [6 ] [domain-test]
  [HW-Accounting-Level(Huawei-84)     ] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Up-Priority(Huawei-61)          ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
Nov 23 18:55:37 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:56:55.873 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [HW-Down-Priority(Huawei-62)        ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-User-Mac(Huawei-153)            ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [HW-Acct-Update-Address(Huawei-159) ] [6 ] [0]
Nov 23 18:55:42 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:00.839 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  Radius Sent a Packet
  Server Template: 1
  Server IP   : 172.16.72.6
  NAS IP      : 172.16.72.90
  Vpn-Instance: -
  Server Port : 1813
  NAS Port    : 1813
  Protocol: Standard
  Code    : Account request
  Len     : 312
  ID      : 19
  [User-Name(1)                       ] [9 ] [usertest]
  [NAS-Port(5)                        ] [6 ] [3153920]
  [NAS-IP-Address(4)                  ] [6 ] [172.16.72.90]
  [Framed-IP-Address(8)               ] [6 ] [10.0.0.2]
  [NAS-Identifier(32)                 ] [9 ] [CERBERO]
  [Acct-Status-Type(40)               ] [6 ] [1] [Start]
  [Acct-Delay-Time(41)                ] [6 ] [4]
  [Acct-Session-Id(44)                ] [35] [CERBERO0030200000000095bc60002040]
  [Acct-Authentic(45)                 ] [6 ] [1] [RADIUS]
  [Event-Timestamp(55)                ] [6 ] [1543035415] [2018-11-24 04:56:55]
Nov 23 18:55:42 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:00.839 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [NAS-Port-Type(61)                  ] [6 ] [15] [Ethernet]
  [Calling-Station-Id(31)             ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [NAS-Port-Id(87)                    ] [35] [slot=0;subslot=3;port=2;vlanid=0;]
  [Service-Type(6)                    ] [6 ] [2] [Framed]
  [Framed-Protocol(7)                 ] [6 ] [1] [PPP]
  [Connect-Info(77)                   ] [12] [1000000000]
  [Idle-Timeout(28)                   ] [6 ] [0]
  [Session-Timeout(27)                ] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-IP-Host-Address(Huawei-60)      ] [34] [10.0.0.2 18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [HW-Priority(Huawei-22)             ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-Connect-ID(Huawei-26)           ] [6 ] [8256]
  [HW-Domain-Name(Huawei-138)         ] [6 ] [domain-test]
  [HW-Accounting-Level(Huawei-84)     ] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Up-Priority(Huawei-61)          ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
Nov 23 18:55:42 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:00.839 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [HW-Down-Priority(Huawei-62)        ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-User-Mac(Huawei-153)            ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [HW-Acct-Update-Address(Huawei-159) ] [6 ] [0]
Nov 23 18:55:47 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:05.836 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  Radius Sent a Packet
  Server Template: 1
  Server IP   : 172.16.72.6
  NAS IP      : 172.16.72.90
  Vpn-Instance: -
  Server Port : 1813
  NAS Port    : 1813
  Protocol: Standard
  Code    : Account request
  Len     : 396
  ID      : 20
  [User-Name(1)                       ] [9 ] [usertest]
  [NAS-Port(5)                        ] [6 ] [3153920]
  [NAS-IP-Address(4)                  ] [6 ] [172.16.72.90]
  [Framed-IP-Address(8)               ] [6 ] [10.0.0.2]
  [NAS-Identifier(32)                 ] [9 ] [CERBERO]
  [Acct-Status-Type(40)               ] [6 ] [2] [Stop]
  [Acct-Delay-Time(41)                ] [6 ] [0]
  [Acct-Input-Octets(42)              ] [6 ] [162640]
  [Acct-Output-Octets(43)             ] [6 ] [143687]
  [Acct-Session-Id(44)                ] [35] [CERBERO0030200000000095bc60002040]
Nov 23 18:55:47 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:05.836 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [Acct-Authentic(45)                 ] [6 ] [1] [RADIUS]
  [Acct-Session-Time(46)              ] [6 ] [0]
  [Acct-Input-Packets(47)             ] [6 ] [296]
  [Acct-Output-Packets(48)            ] [6 ] [255]
  [Acct-Terminate-Cause(49)           ] [6 ] [10] [NAS Request]
  [Acct-Input-Gigawords(52)           ] [6 ] [0]
  [Acct-Output-Gigawords(53)          ] [6 ] [0]
  [Event-Timestamp(55)                ] [6 ] [1543035425] [2018-11-24 04:57:05]
  [NAS-Port-Type(61)                  ] [6 ] [15] [Ethernet]
  [Calling-Station-Id(31)             ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [NAS-Port-Id(87)                    ] [35] [slot=0;subslot=3;port=2;vlanid=0;]
  [Service-Type(6)                    ] [6 ] [2] [Framed]
  [Framed-Protocol(7)                 ] [6 ] [1] [PPP]
  [Connect-Info(77)                   ] [12] [1000000000]
  [Idle-Timeout(28)                   ] [6 ] [0]
Nov 23 18:55:47 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:05.836 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [Session-Timeout(27)                ] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-IP-Host-Address(Huawei-60)      ] [34] [10.0.0.2 18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [HW-Priority(Huawei-22)             ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-Connect-ID(Huawei-26)           ] [6 ] [8256]
  [HW-Domain-Name(Huawei-138)         ] [6 ] [domain-test]
  [HW-Accounting-Level(Huawei-84)     ] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Up-Priority(Huawei-61)          ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-Down-Priority(Huawei-62)        ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Input-Octets(Huawei-144)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Output-Octets(Huawei-145)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Input-Packets(Huawei-146)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Output-Packets(Huawei-147)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Input-Gigawords(Huawei-148)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Output-Gigawords(Huawei-149)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-User-Mac(Huawei-153)            ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
Nov 23 18:55:47 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:05.836 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [HW-Acct-Update-Address(Huawei-159) ] [6 ] [0]
Nov 23 18:55:51 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:10.835 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  Radius Sent a Packet
  Server Template: 1
  Server IP   : 172.16.72.6
  NAS IP      : 172.16.72.90
  Vpn-Instance: -
  Server Port : 1813
  NAS Port    : 1813
  Protocol: Standard
  Code    : Account request
  Len     : 396
  ID      : 21
  [User-Name(1)                       ] [9 ] [usertest]
  [NAS-Port(5)                        ] [6 ] [3153920]
  [NAS-IP-Address(4)                  ] [6 ] [172.16.72.90]
  [Framed-IP-Address(8)               ] [6 ] [10.0.0.2]
  [NAS-Identifier(32)                 ] [9 ] [CERBERO]
  [Acct-Status-Type(40)               ] [6 ] [2] [Stop]
  [Acct-Delay-Time(41)                ] [6 ] [5]
  [Acct-Input-Octets(42)              ] [6 ] [162640]
  [Acct-Output-Octets(43)             ] [6 ] [143687]
  [Acct-Session-Id(44)                ] [35] [CERBERO0030200000000095bc60002040]
Nov 23 18:55:51 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:10.835 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [Acct-Authentic(45)                 ] [6 ] [1] [RADIUS]
  [Acct-Session-Time(46)              ] [6 ] [0]
  [Acct-Input-Packets(47)             ] [6 ] [296]
  [Acct-Output-Packets(48)            ] [6 ] [255]
  [Acct-Terminate-Cause(49)           ] [6 ] [10] [NAS Request]
  [Acct-Input-Gigawords(52)           ] [6 ] [0]
  [Acct-Output-Gigawords(53)          ] [6 ] [0]
  [Event-Timestamp(55)                ] [6 ] [1543035425] [2018-11-24 04:57:05]
  [NAS-Port-Type(61)                  ] [6 ] [15] [Ethernet]
  [Calling-Station-Id(31)             ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [NAS-Port-Id(87)                    ] [35] [slot=0;subslot=3;port=2;vlanid=0;]
  [Service-Type(6)                    ] [6 ] [2] [Framed]
  [Framed-Protocol(7)                 ] [6 ] [1] [PPP]
  [Connect-Info(77)                   ] [12] [1000000000]
  [Idle-Timeout(28)                   ] [6 ] [0]
Nov 23 18:55:51 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:10.835 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [Session-Timeout(27)                ] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-IP-Host-Address(Huawei-60)      ] [34] [10.0.0.2 18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
  [HW-Priority(Huawei-22)             ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-Connect-ID(Huawei-26)           ] [6 ] [8256]
  [HW-Domain-Name(Huawei-138)         ] [6 ] [domain-test]
  [HW-Accounting-Level(Huawei-84)     ] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Up-Priority(Huawei-61)          ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-Down-Priority(Huawei-62)        ] [6 ] [15] [Unchangeable]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Input-Octets(Huawei-144)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Output-Octets(Huawei-145)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Input-Packets(Huawei-146)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Output-Packets(Huawei-147)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Input-Gigawords(Huawei-148)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-Acct-ipv6-Output-Gigawords(Huawei-149)] [6 ] [0]
  [HW-User-Mac(Huawei-153)            ] [19] [18:66:da:fe:c7:a9]
Nov 23 18:55:51 172.16.97.2 Nov 24 2018 04:57:10.835 CERBERO %%01BRASRDS/7/BRRDS_DBG_PACKET(d):VS=Admin-VS-CID=0x8398041c;
  [HW-Acct-Update-Address(Huawei-159) ] [6 ] [0]
```

I got to sniffer the inside Radius, but here seems different, it seems the Radius does not answering the accounting initialized by the Huawei.

[image]

**Even you guys does not have the solution for this specific vendor, tell me if it happens with other vendors. **

### Update

Huawei configuration:

```
radius-server group testGROUP
 radius-server shared-key-cipher %^%#IK"53fC*k)_tVf3`,*FQmrAqAld%<-rHS~7O@CB3%^%#    
 radius-server authentication 172.16.72.6 1812 weight 0 
 radius-server accounting 172.16.72.6 1813 weight 0 
 radius-server accounting retransmit 3 timeout 3 
 undo radius-server user-name domain-included
 radius-server test-aaa accounting-start-packet send

 authentication-scheme default
  authentication-mode local radius

 accounting-scheme testAccounting
  accounting send-update

domain testDomain
  authentication-scheme default
  accounting-scheme testAccounting
  radius-server group testGROUP
  ip-pool pool1

interface Virtual-Template0
 ppp authentication-mode auto

interface GigabitEthernet0/3/2
 undo shutdown
 pppoe-server bind Virtual-Template 0
 undo dcn
 bas
 #
  access-type layer2-subscriber default-domain authentication testDomain
 #
#
```

Comment: The problem is with the radius server. It's getting the accounting requests, but apparently is ignoring them.

Comment: This Radius is a proprietary software. We already open the ticket to the company, but they say that the problem is with Huawei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the accounting session was creating a id with 33 bytes and Radius was not accepting it, that explain reason of he was ignoring the accounting initiated by the Huawei.

[acct-session-id-version](https://support.huawei.com/hedex/pages/EDOC100012228230006918/02/EDOC100012228230006918/02/resources/ne/acct-session-id-version.html) was default (version 1), after alter to version 3 the accounting is accepted.